# How to display JSON objects in Angular2 views

Tags: javascript, json, angular

New to Angular and I have the JSON available to me in the console. So the backend/REST call is functioning correctly. However I'm struggling to understand how to show the JSON in the view for the component.

### Console screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

### app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { TradeshowComponent } from './tradeshow/tradeshow.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-container'
})

export class AppComponent {

    constructor() { }
}
```

### tradeshow.component.ts

```
import { Component, View } from 'angular2/core';
import { CORE_DIRECTIVES, NgIf, NgFor } from 'angular2/common';
import { DataService } from '../shared/services/data.service';
import { DashboardLayoutComponent } from '../dashboard_layout/dashboard_layout.component';
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/http';


@Component({
  selector: 'tradeshow',
  providers: [DataService, HTTP_PROVIDERS]
})

@View({
  templateUrl: 'src/app/tradeshow/tradeshow.component.html',
  directives: [DashboardLayoutComponent, NgIf, NgFor]
})

export class TradeshowComponent {

    constructor(private _dataService: DataService) { this.getTradeShows() }


  getTradeShows() {
    this._dataService.getTradeShows()
        .subscribe(
            tradeshows => this.tradeShows = tradeshows
            error =>  console.error('Error: ' + err)
         );
     }
}
```

And the HTML I'm using is:

### tradeshow.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="#tradeshows of tradeshows">{{ tradeshows.name }}</div>
```

And my service looks like this:

### data.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response } from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {Config} from '../../config/config';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
 export class DataService {

    // API path
    baseUrl: string = '/api';
    authUrl: string;
    apiUrl: string;
    registerUrl: string;

    constructor(private _http: Http, private _config: Config) {
         this.apiUrl = this._config.get('apiUrl') + this.baseUrl;
         this.authUrl = this._config.get('apiUrl') + '/auth';
         this.registerUrl = this._config.get('apiUrl') + '/register';
     }

    getTradeShows() {
        return this._http.get(this.getApiUrl('/tradeshow/list'))
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
           .catch(this.handleError);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug

```
  getTradeShows() {
    this._dataService.getTradeShows()
        .subscribe(
            tradeshows => this.getTradeShows() = tradeshows,
            error =>  console.error('Error: ' + err)
        );
  }
```

it should be

```
  getTradeShows() {
    this._dataService.getTradeShows()
        .subscribe(
            tradeshows => this.tradeshows = tradeshows
            error =>  console.error('Error: ' + err)
        );
  }
```

You can remove `NgIf, NgFor` from

```
  directives: [DashboardLayoutComponent, NgIf, NgFor]
```

these are now globally available.

Change

```
 <div *ngFor="#tradeshows of tradeshows">{{ tradeshows.name }}</div>
```

to

```
 <div *ngFor="#tradeshow of tradeshows">{{ tradeshow.name }}</div>
```

`@Child()` was removed a while ago

```
})

@View({
```

should be replaced by `,`

I made an error in this line

```
tradeshows => this.tradeShows = tradeshows
```

should be (lowercase S)

```
tradeshows => this.tradeshows = tradeshows
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/1sfj6I?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks. Fixed this and updated the code above. I'm not seeing any console errors on the `tradeshow.component.html` although no result is showing on the front end for `{{ tradeshows.name }}`. Area is blank and in devtools shows `<!--template bindings={}-->`

Comment: I update my answer. Do you need more information? Do you get any error message? What is not working as expected?

Comment: Thanks again, removed `NgIf, NgFor` and updated. However DevTools still only showing `<!--template bindings={}-->` in that area. Only console error I see is `undefined:1 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: object is not a constructor(…)`

Comment: Seems you are not calling `getTradeShows()` anywhete. Add `this.getTradeShows()` at the end of the constructor of your component.

Comment: I updated my answer again. Please tell if these suggestions result in different errors.

Comment: I've updated the `constructor` line in my original post. Can you have a look and let me know if that is where it should be called? Still seeing the blank space on the page.

Comment: That's the right place. What's the outcome of the change? Time for bed I might not respond anymore today.

Comment: I updated my answer - also with a running Plunker example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111036/discussion-between-s0rfi949-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, is it possible to load json file and store it inside object and render object data in HTML elements ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095056/angular2-read-json-file-using-http

Comment: `<div>{{myObject | json }}</div>`