# angular2 read json file using http

Tags: javascript, json, angular

trying to read json file from my local project for some basic config.

code:

```
myM: any;

constructor(private http: Http) {
     this.http.get('config.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.parseHeaderJSON(res);
        });
}
parseHeaderJSON(res) {
    this.myM = res;
}
```

HTML:

```
<li><a href="{{myM.home_header.whatis.link_url}}" class="ripple-effect">{{myM.home_header.whatis.link_name}}</a></li>
```

but it always logs on console as **undefined..**

if I place `console.dir(res)` instead of value assign then it prints my object data but don't know why it does not assign to variable !!!

can anyone tell me where am I wrong ?

**UPDATE**

json file content:

```
{
  "home_header": 
  {   
  "servicesweoffer":
      {
        "lable_name":"SERVICES WE OFFER",
        "link_url":""        
      },
  "pricing":
      {
        "lable_name":"PRICING",
        "link_url":""
      },      
  "contacutus":
      {
        "lable_name":"CONTACT US",
        "link_url":""
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.dir(this.myM)` will print `undefined` because

```
this.http.get('config.json')
    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
    .subscribe(res => this.myM = res);
```

is an **async** operation. Meaning `http.get` will return you something after a time (depending on network speed and other stuff) and you can do something with this response inside the http callback which is inside `subscribe`.

That is why if you place `console.dir(res)` inside the callback it prints the value. So when you are assigning `this.myM = res;` you are not doing anything wrong, it just takes a little time to do this operation.

Example:

```
constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http.get('config.json')
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe((res) => {
             //do your operations with the response here
             this.myM = res;
             this.someRandomFunction(res);  
        );
}

someRandomFunction(res){
    console.dir(res);
}
```

```
<li><a href="{{myM?.home_header?.whatis?.link_url}}" class="ripple-effect">{{myM?.home_header?.whatis?.link_name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: still it's undefined.. I have tried to print `myM` in `ngOnInit` as well but though also not getting it.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ `ngOnInit` executes little after the `constructor`. If you want to do an operation with this response, you have to do it inside the callback.

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ Where do you want to read the values? Show me a use case.

Comment: I want to make all this read json file and all using service.. so I just have to call it's function that `readHeader` so it will give me it's values.. I will add further config and error data text inside my json so everything will be there in json gradually. so for to read and json and process content I want to have a service..

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ then call the services functions inside the `http.get` callback?

Comment: hello, how can I render this object data in `HTML`. Like I want to make a dynamic header menu r kind of thing. I've directly use it but it shows me that my main object `myM` is undefined because it's `async` call.

Comment: Can you edit your question with this use case as an example?

Comment: please see updated code, while loading object inside `li` it shows me `undefined`.

Comment: change the `<li>` like I did in my updated answer. Put the ?'s

Comment: hello, error is not there but that html element does not load. empty string element only. Can we do something like we can load it before we render HTML ?

Comment: Take a look at this example. I've set the variable to something after 5 seconds and it is displayed. http://plnkr.co/edit/7Iex1VHgcjRlumyBPlKQ?p=preview

Comment: so how does it apply to my case ? shall I have to add `ngAfterViewInit`, can't I do anything else ! because it does not look good to display menu after 1 or 2 second !

Comment: @JavaCuriousღ well.. you can show a loading screen while you make your http call..

Answer (score 0):

Scope of this not working in subscribe

```
myM: any;

constructor(private http: Http) {
    let _self = this;
     this.http.get('config.json')
     .map((res: Response) => res.json())
     .subscribe(
        res => _self.myM = res
     );
        console.dir(this.myM);
}
```

Comment: still it's undefined.

Comment: @anshuVersatile

You can use this inside the function because it's an ES6 Arrow Function which is non-binding of this.